# What design patterns might be useful for creating a logical report engine?

Tags: database, algorithm, design-patterns, database-design

I am designing (and coding) a report engine, that produces the aggregated **data** for a report - this is **not** about the presentation layer.

Example :
I've got a database full of people records. Each person in the DB has about 15 attributes.

My report needs to

1. Select a specific group of people, according to about 15 business rules. These better resemble an logical flowing algorithm than a mere WHERE clause, for example : Take all the people who are aged 18-25 and are self-employed. If there are less than 100 people, also include the 25-28 age group... If still less than 100, take also the people who are students... This goes on...
2. After I've got the specific group I'm working on, I need to create more than a few data sets, that are by different groupings, and include different metrics. For example, the average height - grouped by weight, the average income - grouped by age ... These also have complex business rules, like - If an age group has less than 5 people in it, aggregate it with an adjacent group that has the smaller number of people in it, but anyway always show the 20-30 age group independently....

My main concern is that I've got **a lot** of business rules, that are pretty similar in form, but have all kinds of different small details. I want to make sure I write this in a maintainable and understandable method, as in my experience this usually winds up being a really long file with a lot of nested if-else that are horrible to maintain.

I have a pretty big amount of reports and I'd like to pre-compute as many of the reports as I can. I do know that there are actually an endless amount of report criteria possible, so I will also need to produce reports on the fly. I'd like to keep the logic for the pre-computing and for the ad-hoc reporting in one place.

The report data here IS the product, so these need to be handed out pretty quickly, and go out to the end-user.

The current design includes the data being stored in CouchDB and the processing being done on nodeJS. These can be changed if there is something out there that will be much easier/faster to use. I have a couple of hundred thousands of records , I wouldn't say this is 'big-data' (but of course - this might grow).

Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be having multiple business rules which will need to interact with each other, the first design pattern which comes to mind is the [Decorator Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/decorator-pattern.html). The aim of this pattern is to add information to a given object as it passes through. So you could have a behaviour which given a list of people, identifies those which are in a particular age group. It then passes this sub list to another behaviour which applies, for instance, sort by gender, etc.

However, since business rules are prone to change, you would need to make your code flexible. To do that, in my opinion you should use the [Strategy Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/strategy-pattern.html) since it will allow you to specify various algorithms which you can then pass to your reporting algorithm (the main core of your application which takes care of rendering everything as the user would like it, without concerning itself with what kind of information you are working with. This should make it easier to change and/or extend the behaviour of your reporting tool.

Lastly, if you are working with databases, which I am assuming you are, you could use the [Singleton Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/singleton-pattern.html) to manage your database connections and interactions. That being said, it is most likely that you will find something of this sort already available for the language of your choice.